# Blob name patterns of Azure Functions in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am implementing an Azure Function in Python which is triggered by a file uploaded to blob storage. I want to specify the pattern of the filename and use its parts inside my code as follows:

*function.json:*

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "inputblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "dev/sources/{filename}.csv",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

The executed *__init__.py* file looks as follows:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(inputblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info('Python Blob trigger function processed %s', inputblob.filename)
```

The error message that I get is: `AttributeError: 'InputStream' object has no attribute 'filename'`.
As a reference, I used [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python).

Did I do something wrong or is it not possible to achieve what I want in Python?

Comment: The documentation you point to uses `inputblob.name`, not `.filename`.

Comment: Please notice that it should be name instead of filename.

Comment: `myblob.name` in my case gives me `/dev/sources/myfile.csv`, but I would like to extract only `myfile`.

Comment: Please have a look of this blog: https://medium.com/@loopjockey/structuring-azure-blobs-for-functions-8305ba427356 Azure blob storage is flat, So there is no built-in method to get what you want.

Comment: I have update the answer again, please let me know whether it is what you want.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function code should be this:

```
import logging
import os

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    head, filename = os.path.split(myblob.name)
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name without extension: {name}\n"
                 f"Filename: {filename}")
```

It should be name instead of filename.:)

Comment: I actually changed this variable on purpose for testing. Because executing the function as you suggested, doesn't give me the actual string that is between the path and the extension, but it gives me the full path including the extension. myblob.name would be `/dev/sources/myfile.csv`and not only `myfile`.

Comment: @elyptikus Please notice that the blob storage is flat, it it not a hierarchical storage. So you can not get the filename directly.

Comment: @elyptikus Please have a look of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#blob-names

Comment: @elyptikus Your idea will lead to this situation: dev/sources/1.csv, dev/sources/1/2.csv and dev/sources/1/2/3.csv will both trigger this function and in your situation the filename will be 1, 1/2, 1/2/3.

Comment: I see what you want to tell me but this is not what I am asking for. My problem is, that I can not extract the filename at all. How would you proceed to extract the filename 1, 1/2, or 1/2/3? Could you please share some code that gives these outputs?

Comment: Great, Thanks for the edit of the code. This solves my question at least in a other way. But so you are saying that it is not possible to use the defined pattern (i.e. {filename}.csv) as a variable (i.e. {filename}) in my Python code as it is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python#filter-on-blob-name)?

Comment: @elyptikus Update again, Is it what you want?

Comment: @elyptikus I think 1/2/3 is not you want, may be 3 is what you want? My update code can give you filename without extension. It my code what you want?

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem. The original question was if it is possible to use the defined pattern inside my Python code. And according to the discussion now it is not possible. I wanted to have a clean way to extract data from the filename. Parsing `myblob.name` is a possible solution. Thanks!

Comment: @elyptikus Hi, if my answer helps you, can you [mark it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsESi.png) to end this question?:)

Answer (score 1):

I know its really late but I was going through the same problem and I got a getaway so I decided to answer you here.

You can just do reassemble the string in python.

inside *init.py* -

```
filenameraw = inputblob.name
filenameraw = filenameraw.split('/')[-1]
filenameraw = filenameraw.replace(".csv","")
```

with this you'll get your desired output. :)